# Regex for a min number value of 125?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, input, zurb-foundation

I have an input that requires a minimum number value of 125. I am new to regex, and using Foundation's Abide for validation which as far as I can tell does not have specific mix/max support. I was hoping for a regex to set in the pattern attribute. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: AFAIK regexes can't do that. You could possibly make it work for numbers between 0 and 999, but not for an arbitrarily large number of digits. Either way, it's probably simpler to just convert to an int and check the value.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: Carl, I'm using a regex because Abide uses a "pattern" attr doesn't seem to support min or max for validation according to it's native library, even though it's based off html 5. Now it could be that going with a simple jquery condition would make more sense here and it's looking more like I should, rather than limit myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any regex to comprehensively validate the value of a number is going to be beefy. I'd suggest just parsing the number to an `int` and then checking it.

In Javascript:

```
if (parseInt(numberString) >= 125)
{
    // number is at least 125.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I feel like regex it would over-complicate things at this point.  I would use jquery to basically do what you did above.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just need to cover 3 or greater digits.

```
 #  ^[0-9]*(?:12[5-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3,})$

 ^     
 [0-9]* 
 (?:
      12 [5-9] 
   |  
      1 [3-9] [0-9] 
   |  
      [2-9] [0-9]{2} 
   |  
      [1-9] [0-9]{3,} 
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it through Regex , you can try this expression :

```
([1-9][2-9][5-9])|([2-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9]\d{3}\d*)
```

I have tested it in javascript and it is working fine in there :

```
var pattern = /([1-9][2-9][5-9])|([2-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9]\d{3}\d*)/;
console.log(pattern.test('120'));   //false
console.log(pattern.test('125'));   // true
console.log(pattern.test('200'));   // true
console.log(pattern.test('10000'));   // true
console.log(pattern.test('99999'));   // true
```

Comment: I think its a little trickier. You'd have to match 310 or something.

Comment: What about the number 200? This also doesn't account for leading zeros.

Comment: right , I agree there's a lot missing from my answer. Let me add up the missing logic in there.

Comment: alright , updates done , the new regex works for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question you want to add 125 as a minimum value, then you can handle it like

```
/([1-9][0-9]{3,}|12[5-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][0-9])/
```

Find the test cases added to this below link:

https://regex101.com/r/h6bScL/1